# PHP - How to display data from array into a tree or table?

Tags: php, arrays, tree, multidimensional-array

Currently, I have data retrieved from SELECT and converted into PHP assoc array. Thus, I got this array.

```
[0] => array
(
    [Gattung] => 'Gattung_A'
    [Untergattung] => null
    [Sektion] => null
    [Untersektion] => null
    [Serie] => null
    [Unterserie] => null
    [Art] => 'Art_A'
    [Unterart] => null
    [Varietaet] => null
    [SubVarietaet] => null
    [Form] => 'Form_A'
    [Unterform] => null
    [SpezialForm] => null
    [Hybride] => null
    [Blendling] => null
    [Sorte] => null
)
[1] => array
(
    [Gattung] => 'Gattung_A'
    [Untergattung] => null
    [Sektion] => null
    [Untersektion] => null
    [Serie] => null
    [Unterserie] => null
    [Art] => 'Art_B'
    [Unterart] => null
    [Varietaet] => 'Variant_G'
    [SubVarietaet] => null
    [Form] => 'Form_B'
    [Unterform] => null
    [SpezialForm] => null
    [Hybride] => null
    [Blendling] => null
    [Sorte] => null
)
[2] => array
(
    [Gattung] => 'Gattung_B'
    [Untergattung] => null
    [Sektion] => null
    [Untersektion] => null
    [Serie] => null
    [Unterserie] => null
    [Art] => 'Art_C'
    [Unterart] => null
    [Varietaet] => 'Variant_A'
    [SubVarietaet] => null
    [Form] => null
    [Unterform] => null
    [SpezialForm] => null
    [Hybride] => null
    [Blendling] => null
    [Sorte] => null
)
......... 
Nearly ~300k records
```

So far, I have fixed my array into one dimensional array based on unique values by using `array_unique`. This is my result:

```
(
  [0] => 'Gattung|Gattung_A'
  [1] => 'Art|Art_A'
  [3] => 'Form|Form_A'
  [5] => 'Art|ArtB'
  [7] => 'Varietaet|Variant_G'
  [9] => 'Form|Form_G'
  [11] => 'Gattung|Gattung_B'
  [13] => 'Art|Art_C'
  [15] => 'Varietaet|Variant_A'
}
```

However, my result is not well grouped. I need to display it on a page, so something like building a hierarchical system.

Question:
@Melsi I hope my second edit will purify my queston.

> How to display the data into a tree
>   form (See Edit 2) or a table (See Edit
>   1)?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

What I am doing is to create something like FULLTEXT search in several tables. This is the query to join all the tables:
(All FKs have index to each table's id )

```
SELECT 
    tGa.Gattung AS Gattung, 
    tUG.Untergattung AS Untergattung,
    tSe.Sektion AS Sektion,
    tUS.Untersektion AS Untersektion,
    tSer.Serie AS Serie,
    tUser.Unterserie AS Unterserie, 
    tA.Art AS Art,
    tUa.Unterart AS Unterart,
    tV.Varietaet AS Varietaet, 
    tSV.SubVarietaet AS SubVarietaet,
    tF.Form AS Form, 
    tUF.Unterform AS Unterform,
    tSF.SpezialForm AS SpezialForm, 
    tH.Hybride AS Hybride, 
    tBL.Blendling AS Blendling, 
    tSo.Sorte AS Sorte 
FROM 
        botanischername AS tBot
    LEFT JOIN ( gattung AS tGa ) ON ( tBot.ID_Ga = tGa.ID_Ga )
    LEFT JOIN ( untergattung AS tUg ) ON (  tBot.ID_UG = tUg.ID_UG )
    LEFT JOIN ( sektion AS tSe ) ON ( tSe.ID_Se = tBot.ID_Se )
    LEFT JOIN ( untersektion AS tUS ) ON ( tUS.ID_US = tBot.ID_US )
    LEFT JOIN ( serie AS tSer ) ON ( tSer.ID_Ser = tBot.ID_Ser )
    LEFT JOIN ( unterserie AS tUSer ) ON ( tUser.ID_USer = tBot.ID_USer )
    LEFT JOIN ( art AS tA ) ON ( tA.ID_A = tBot.ID_A )
    LEFT JOIN ( unterart AS tUa ) ON ( tUa.ID_UA = tBot.ID_UA )
    LEFT JOIN ( varietaet AS tV ) ON ( tV.ID_V = tBot.ID_V )
    LEFT JOIN ( subvarietaet AS tSV ) ON ( tSV.ID_SV = tBot.ID_SV)
    LEFT JOIN ( form AS tF ) ON ( tF.ID_F = tBot.ID_F )
    LEFT JOIN ( unterform AS tUF ) ON ( tUF.ID_UF = tBot.ID_UF )
    LEFT JOIN ( spezialform AS tSF ) ON ( tSF.ID_SF = tBot.ID_SF )
    LEFT JOIN ( hybride AS tH ) ON ( tH.ID_H = tBot.ID_H )
    LEFT JOIN ( blendling AS tBL ) ON ( tBL.ID_BL = tBot.ID_BL )
    LEFT JOIN ( sorte AS tSo ) ON ( tSo.ID_So = tBot.ID_So )
    LEFT JOIN ( status AS tST 
                 CROSS JOIN pflanze AS tPfl) ON 
                        ( tST.ID_ST = tBot.ID_ST AND tPfl.ID = tBot.ID )

    WHERE 
            tGa.Gattung LIKE #1_Word#        OR 
            tUG.Untergattung LIKE #2_Word#  OR
    tSe.Sektion LIKE #3_Word# OR 
    tUS.Untersektion LIKE #4_Word# OR 
    tSer.Serie LIKE #5_Word# OR 
    tUser.Unterserie LIKE #6_Word# OR
    tA.Art LIKE #7_Word# OR
    tUa.Unterart LIKE #8_Word# OR
    tV.Varietaet LIKE #9_Word# OR 
    tSV.SubVarietaet LIKE #10_Word# OR
    tF.Form LIKE #11_Word# oR 
    tUF.Unterform LIKE #12_Word# OR 
    tSF.SpezialForm LIKE #13_Word# oR
    tH.Hybride LIKE #14_Word# oR
    tBL.Blendling LIKE #15_Word# OR
    tSo.Sorte LIKE #16_Word#
```

I know that by using `LIKE %xxx% OR` is a heavy process. If you want to suggest me another way, it is fine.

My expected result is something like:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|      |             |       |______________________________Detail_____________| 
| Num  | Gattung     | Art   | Form      | Varietaet  | ...... | the other cols|
|------|-------------|-------|-----------|------------|--------|---------------|
| 1.   | Gattung A   | Art A | Form A    |            |        |               |
|      |             | <same | Form B    |            |        |               |
|      |    | data or Art A> |           |            |        |               |
|      |             | Art B | Form B    | Variant G  |        |               |
| 2.   | Gattung B   | Art C |           | Variant A  |        |               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                              Back 1 2 3   Next
```

**EDIT 2 : Concise the question.**

Or in tree form,

```
                   ----- Art A ------ Form A
                   |               |
                   |               -- Form B
1.   Gattung A ----|---- Art B ------ Form B ---- Variant G

2.   Gattung B --------- Art C ------ Variant A 

 ... And so on.
```

Comment: when you say "Currently, I have a data retrieved from SELECT and converted into PHP assoc array" -- can you put the code up you are using for that?  I would alter that code -- either the QUERY, the php or both.  Then you don't have to be so heavy with your processing afterward.

Answer (score 2):

@exodream

Thank you for you comment.

This is my new answer to your question, it avoids empty lines, if you need to avoid empty coloumns or need something else let me know.

```
<?php 

        //make the labels
        $labels=array('Gattung','Untergattung','Sektion','Untersektion','Serie',
    'Unterserie','Art','Unterart','Varietaet','SubVarietaet','Form','Unterform',
    'SpezialForm','Hybride','Blendling','Sorte' );  

    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

    //select database
    mysql_query("drop database if exists `test_db`;")or die(mysql_error());  
    mysql_query("create database `test_db`;")or die(mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db("test_db") or die(mysql_error());

    //create table 
    mysql_query(" drop table if exists `test_table`;")or die(mysql_error());  


    mysql_query("   
    CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
        `Gattung` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Untergattung` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Sektion` char(30)  NULL  , 
        `Untersektion` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Serie` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Unterserie` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Art` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Unterart` char(30)  NULL  ,    
        `Varietaet` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `SubVarietaet` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Form` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Unterform` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `SpezialForm` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Hybride` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Blendling` char(30)  NULL  ,
        `Sorte` char(30)  NULL   
    )
    COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB;") or die(mysql_error());  



     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test_table`  VALUES 
     ('Gattung_A',null,null,null,null,null,'Art_A',null,null,null,'Form_A',null,null,null,null,null  ) ") 
     or die(mysql_error());    

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test_table`  VALUES 
     ('Gattung_A',null,null,null,null,null,'Art_A',null,null,null,'Form_A',null,null,null ,null,null ) ") 
     or die(mysql_error());    

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test_table`  VALUES 
     ('Gattung_B',null,null,null,null,null,'Art_C',null,'Variant_A',null,null,null,null,null,null,null ) ") 
     or die(mysql_error());   

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test_table`  VALUES 
     (null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null ) ") 
     or die(mysql_error());   


     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test_table`  VALUES 
     ('Gattung_Q',null,null,null,null,null,'Art_C',null,'Variant_A',null,'Form_W',null,null,null,null,null ) ") 
     or die(mysql_error());   

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test_table`  VALUES 
     ('Gattung_Q',null,'test','test','test','test','Art_S','test','Variant_Y','test','Form_H','test','test','test','test','last' ) ") 
     or die(mysql_error());   


        //get result        
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test_table` ;")
           or die(mysql_error());   



    normal_display();      
    non_empty_row_display();        
    non_empty_column_display(); 

    function non_empty_row_display()
    { 
        //get data
        global $result;
        $final_array=array();   

        global $result;
        mysql_data_seek ($result , 0);

        print '<b><br><h2>TABLE: 2 NON EMPTY VALUES OF EACH ROW</h2></b>';
        print '<table border=7 bordercolor=orange >';
        $index=0;
        $color=array('#66CCFF','#00FF00');
        //for every row of the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $current_row='';
            //for every coloumn
            foreach ($row as  $value) 
                //if value is not null
                if($value!=null)//then keep it 
                    $current_row .=  $value.' | ';

            if($current_row!='')
                echo '<tr bgcolor=',$color[$index%2],'><th>ROW ',$index++,'</th><td>',$current_row,'</td></tr>',
                        '<tr><td colspan=2 height=5 bgcolor=pink></td></tr>'; 
        }//while
        echo '</table>'; 

    }//function


    function normal_display()
    {
        print '<b><h2>TABLE:1 Normal display</h2></b>';
        print '<table border=1><tr>';
        global $labels;
        foreach($labels as $value)
            echo '<th>',$value,'</th>';
        print '</tr>';
        global $result;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
        {
            print '<tr>';
            foreach($row as $value)
                echo '<td>',$value,'&nbsp;</td>';
            print '</tr>';
        }//while
        print '</table>';
     }//function



     function non_empty_column_display()
    { 
        //get data
        global $result;   
        mysql_data_seek ($result , 0);

        //for every row of the table
        $final_column=array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
            //for every coloumn
            foreach ($row as  $key => $value) 
                //if value is not null
                if($value!=null)
                    //if $final_column[$key] exists append value to it, otherwise assign value 
                    $final_column[$key]=(isset($final_column[$key]))?$final_column[$key].=$value.'<br>':$value.' <br> ';


        echo '<br><br><h2>Array:1 </h2>The coloumn with index 6 is placed before the one with index 2 in this array 
        because its first non empty value is fetched earlier. Check for your self:<br>';
        echo '<pre>',strip_tags(print_r($final_column,true)),'</pre>';


        //for each mysql table coloumn name
        global $labels;
        foreach($labels as $key => $value)
            //if it exists in the result
            if(array_key_exists($key,$final_column))
                //keep it
                $label_header=(isset($label_header))?$label_header.='<th>'.$value.'</th>':'<th>'.$value.'</th>';


        ksort($final_column);
        echo '<br><br><h2>Array:2 </h2>We can order this. Check for your self:<br>';
        echo '<pre>',strip_tags(print_r($final_column,true)),'</pre>';

        echo '<br><b><h2>TABLE:3 </h2>THIS IS A TABLE WITH NON EMPTY COLOUMNS<b>';
        echo '<table border=1>',$label_header,'<tr>';
        foreach($final_column as $value)
                echo '<td valign=top>',$value,'</td>';
        echo '</tr></table>';



    }//function

    ?>
```

I have already fixed lines 147 and 161 (for previous example), it was a warning, we have to check if a variable exists before concatenation, in your example it would be:

147:

```
$final_column[$key]=(isset($final_column[$key]))?$final_column[$key].=$value.'<br>':$value.' <br> ';
```

161:

```
$label_header=(isset($label_header))?$label_header.='<th>'.$value.'</th>':'<th>'.$value.'</th>';
```

Comment: Undefined offset is often noticed on line 68. And also the table's row doesn't print well. If I add one more data, (i.e. Gattung A, with Art B). I cannot see what was the 'Gattung' for 'Art B'.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Please look at my "edited' question for further detail. BTW, I still got "Undefined offset on line 147" in my php log (I use PHP 5.3.4 with WAMP 2.0).

Comment: I have cut and concise my question. Afterward I do realize that what I really need is, to display is like a hierarchical tree (as in biology naming system).

Comment: **Fix Sentences** 
"... what I really need is, to display a hierarchical tree (just like in biological naming system)."

Comment: the concept in blogs.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database  is same, but the implementation is definitely different. Because it is not necessary to update the data using a table. If you could see more careful in my second edit, what I need is a non-binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

1) if you it is possible to do the sorting / grouping / aggregation in SQL then do it in SQL - not in PHP. SQL and rDBMS are designed and optimized for this.

2) PHP does not have multidimesnional arrays - they are hierarchical.

3) if you don't want nulls in your array don't put them there

4) If you have a primary key for the result set in your data use that for your array key

```
while ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach($r as $key=>$val) {
      if ($val || $val===0 || $val===false) {
         $array[$r['Art']][$key]=$val;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: @aymcbean (1)I have grouped my data well, and remove unnecessary data. The naming system is need several tables to join with. (2) Pardon me if I were stupid, but my teacher said to me that when you declare `$arr[][]` does it mean that I declared 2 dimensional array? (3) It's not possible. (4) I've primary key, but what for? It's not necessary. As a replacement, I am going to group the `Gattung's name field` as a new key.